# return new ModelAndView doesnt work

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

My controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/testAdmin", method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = "application/json")
public ModelAndView testAdmin(@RequestBody Student student) {
    System.out.println(student.getName()+" "+student.getId()+" "+student.getLogin()+" "+student.getPassword());
    return new ModelAndView("showString","student",student.getName());
}
```

My ajax function:

```
 function test2(a,ob) {
    var student={
        id:ob[a].id,
        login:ob[a].login,
        password:ob[a].password,
        name:ob[a].name
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',

        url: "testAdmin",
        data: JSON.stringify(student),
        success: function (response)
        {
            alert("success");
        },
        error : function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {
            alert(status+" "+errorThrown.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

Controller method works, but it doesnt go to other page.
I dont know how to fix it, give an example or information to read

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  You mentioned that the redirect to the new page doesn't work.  Is there a server-side stack trace you can post?  Any information about the error you can provide would be helpful.

Comment: @richie i found that controller return just html code to ajax function
i did 
alert(responce)
and saw a html code